# The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null - Camera flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to open camera through clicking a button I got this error

**Error :**

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CameraHomeScreen(dirty, state: _CameraHomeScreenState#5d87d):

The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: isEmpty
```

And hrer is **my code :**

```
   .
   .
   .
List<CameraDescription> cameras;

    String _videoPath = null;

    Future _recordVideo() async {
      final videoPath = await Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: CameraHomeScreen(cameras)));
      setState(() {
        _videoPath = videoPath;
      });
    }
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: can you please post the whole code , like where you called .isEmpty ?

Comment: thank you, I solved it.

Comment: It just some stupid mistakes :)

Comment: mistakes happen, glad you solved it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I miss to give `cameras` any value, Just I gived `cameras` some values and it works well.

By the way: How I found this mistake?

Added some changes to `isEmpaty` line to know does the application access to next screen or not.

**Before Change :**

```
if (widget.cameras.isEmpty) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**After Change :**

```
if (widget?.cameras?.isEmpty ?? true) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I hope this answer help somebody :)

Comment: maybe `widget?.cameras?.isEmpty == true`